# Declare a VisualStateManager Group Collection as a Resource in a Control Template

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, xaml, controltemplate, arcobjects

I need to create a several styles that represent different point objects that all do the same thing.  To be more specific, it is a bunch of ESRI MarkerSymbols that can either be a Circle, Square, Star, etc but that is probably not relevant to the specific problem.

Each point will behave exactly the same way when the user hovers or clicks on them - this is done through the Visual State Groups like so (I deleted several of the animations to save space:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="shapeElement">
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
                                 To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                 To="1" />
                ...................................................................
            </Storyboard>

        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>

    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="shapeElement2">
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                 To="1" />
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                 To="1" />

                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.1" Duration="0:0:0" 
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="shapeElement2">

                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:0.01"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
                                 To="1.75" />
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                 To="1.75" />
                ...................................................................
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>

</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Since I want to create several shapes that all will use this collection of Visual State Groups how do I turn it into a resource?  In other words, how would I do this:

```
<esri:MarkerSymbol x:Key="CircleLocationPointMarker" OffsetX="6" OffsetY="6"  >
    <esri:MarkerSymbol.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Ellipse x:Name="shapeElement">
                    ..............................................
                </Ellipse>

                <Ellipse x:Name="shapeElement2"> 
                    ..............................................
                </Ellipse>

                <Border x:Name="LocationLabel">
                    ..............................................
                </Border>

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    ---HOW DO I USE A RESOURCE OR SEVERAL RESOURCES??---
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </esri:MarkerSymbol.ControlTemplate>
</esri:MarkerSymbol>
```

and say another one for a Square and a Star, and so on.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Re-Use Animations in VisualStates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666405/re-use-animations-in-visualstates) - I would also love to find a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can think of two possible solutions:

**Number 1:**
Derive from the `MarkerSymbol` and add a public *[Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)* property (or maybe better use [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), now you can develop just one `ControlTemplate` complete with `VisualStates` that uses the newly added property. Wherever you want to use you special marker you can provide a customized shape/geometry or you can further derive from it to create default shape markers:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ShapedMarker" x:Key="ShapedMarkerDefaultTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>...</...>
        <Path x:Name="shapeElement" Data="{TemplateBinding ShapeGeometry}"/>
        <Path x:Name="shapeElement2" Data="{TemplateBinding ShapeGeometry}"/>
        <Border x:Name="LocationLabel"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="ShapedMarker">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource ShapedMarkerDefaultTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

and code

```
public class ShapedMarker : MarkerSymbol
{
    public Geometry ShapeGeometry { get {...} set {...} }
    ...DependencyProperty ... "ShapeGeometry" ...

    public ShapedMarker(){ DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ShapedMarker); }
}

public class CircleLocationPointMarker : ShapedMarker
{
  public CircleLocationPointMarker(){this.ShapeGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();}
}
```

**Number 2:**
Basically what I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666405/re-use-animations-in-visualstates/22668495#22668495). You can write your own utility classes to generate `VisualStates` and all associated `Animations` programmatically, this saves you from writing the same markup over and over again. It is a tried and trusted approach and does not have a performance impact, the animations are only created once. However, this approach is not common and many developers are reluctant to try anything uncommon (an observation I even made in my own team).
The markup could look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"
                    utils:AddAnimations.ScaledAndCollapsed="shapeElement2"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"
                    utils:AddAnimations.ScaledAndVisible="shapeElement2"/>
                <.../>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        ...

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And you can even mix animations that are declared in xaml and animations that are added through your utility methods. The code will respect any existing animations.